# pure CSS mobile hamburger menu doesnt close for onClick of links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hamburger-menu

I've included a snippet of the jquery/html/css for the hamburger. the jquery is what I would like to use to make the mobile menu close upon clicking its links. Currently you must click the X again (css-transformed spans) to do so which is annoying and not nice at all. I've tried ids and classes in all the different html tags and nothing seems to work. Any ideas/tips in the right direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //took this code below from another SO answer that got good upvotes, and while I understand it easily, I can't figure out where to place it in the html...I fear that the CSS transforming and rendering of the menu is what is preventing this from working...

  $('.menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').addClass('open');
  });

  $('.menu a').on("click", function() {
    $('.menu').removeClass('open');
  });


});
```

```css
.sticky-navMobile {
  margin: 0;
  width: max-content;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: plum;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #722f58;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  color: #232323;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  color: #232323;
}


/** Transform all the slices of hamburger into an X. */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  background: rgb(146, 102, 146);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
  background: rgb(146, 102, 146);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
  background: rgb(146, 102, 146);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  margin: -37px 0 0 -10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 45px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: #722f58;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sticky-navMobile">
  <nav>
    <div id="menuToggle">
      <!-- A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click receiver, so you can use the :checked selector on it.-->
      <input type="checkbox" />

      <!-- Some spans to act as a hamburger. They are acting like a real hamburger, not that McDonalds stuff. -->
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>

      <!-- Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button but hey, it's pure CSS magic.-->
      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="#projects">
          <li>Projects</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#bio">
          <li>Personal Info</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#footer">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: since it's a checkbox, you could simply uncheck it on any link click. `$("#menu a").on("click", function () { $('.menu')[0].checked = false; });`

Comment: @gp. The menu isn't the checkbox, it's a sibling of the input. Also, your comment mixes up selectors (class and id).

Comment: @disinfor the menu opens or closes on checkbox checked unchecked state. so the point was to control with the checkbox itself. Regarding selectors mix, it was as per the OP's target website i.e. ul had menu id and checkbox had menu class but anyways point was to use checkbox checked state to hide the menu.

Comment: @gp. yes, correct. And that's what my answer from yesterday does: controls the checkbox.

Comment: the id's and classes mixing was me just messing around trying different things and not getting anywhere, i will go and clear it to the default later, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem, is that `open` and `close` don't mean anything in this context, since it's a checkbox that's causing the menu to open and close.

What you need to do, is traverse up the DOM when you click on the menu or the anchor within the menu, and get the `checked` state of the checkbox. If it's true (which it will be because the menu is open), you set the checked state to `false` and that will trigger the CSS for the menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //took this code below from another SO answer that got good upvotes, and while I understand it easily, I can't figure out where to place it in the html...I fear that the CSS transforming and rendering of the menu is what is preventing this from working...

  $('#menu').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).siblings('input').prop('checked')) {
      $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });

  $('#menu a').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).parent('ul').siblings('input').prop('checked')) {
      $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.sticky-navMobile {
  margin: 0;
  width: max-content;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: plum;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #722f58;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  color: #232323;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  color: #232323;
}


/** Transform all the slices of hamburger into an X. */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  background: rgb(146, 102, 146);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
  background: rgb(146, 102, 146);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
  background: rgb(146, 102, 146);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  margin: -37px 0 0 -10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 45px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: #722f58;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sticky-navMobile">
  <nav>
    <div id="menuToggle">
      <!-- A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click receiver, so you can use the :checked selector on it.-->
      <input type="checkbox" />

      <!-- Some spans to act as a hamburger. They are acting like a real hamburger, not that McDonalds stuff. -->
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>

      <!-- Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button but hey, it's pure CSS magic.-->
      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="#projects">
          <li>Projects</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#bio">
          <li>Personal Info</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#footer">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>
```